# Why can't VSCode's C# extension find dotnet?

Tags: c#, .net

It appears that the C# extension can't find my dotnet path. When I open a C# file, [this is what I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyRoE.png).

I've tried reinstalling the extension, the SDK, even VSCode. I checked the PATH, everything looks fine. Why am I seeing this error?

P.S. When I run `dotnet --list-sdks` in a command prompt, it prints an empty line, even after installing the SDK.

Comment: It could help by knowing what OS you are using and how you went about installing c#/dotnet

Comment: this blog by Scott Hanselman might help: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/dotnet-could-not-execute-because-the-application-was-not-found-or-a-compatible-net-sdk-is-not-installed . Essentially you may have multiple "dotnet.exe" in your path, and cmd just picks the first one, which may not be the one you want. And VS Code might rely on that logic as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, it was due to me having multiple entries in the PATH. Thanks @DirkTrilsbeek!

Comment: Can you give more details about how to solve this in order to help others with the same problem? Maybe you can share the code before and after solutions.

Comment: The code? I'm not allowed to show that. I simply had multiple PATH entries. I uninstalled the SDK, removed all dotnet relating entries from the PATH, then reinstalled the SDK.

Comment: I was not talking about your code itself, I mean an example about how looks before and how must look now in order to help the community. But thanks for the explanation that you just put about uninstall the SDK and the another steps. That can be helpful too.